# How can I add a "Calculated" field in a table that outputs the count of records in the subdatasheet for that record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

For example,

[image]

[image]

The number of instances field shows "1" because there is one record in the subdatasheet associated with the main record. (I currently have the calculated field set to "1" for all records as a placeholder)

Is there a way to have this calculated for every main record automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't have calculated columns that update automatically. You can have a calculated column in a query by defining a column based on a DCount() function.

Another way to do it would be to create a master/detail form pair with both forms set to display in datasheet view. This will present the same way as the raw table datasheet with expanding subrows. Add a text box to the parent form with a function in the ControlSource to determine the count of rows in the detail dataset. A DCount function would work there too.

```
=DCOUNT("*", "DetailTableName", "ForeignKeyColumnInDetailTable = '" & [KeyColumnControlNameOnMasterForm] & "'")
```

If the data type of the key is a string value, you'll need the single quotes in the example. If the data type is numeric, the single quotes aren't needed, so the final concatenation at the end would go away completely. If you happen to be referencing a date, replace the single quotes with hash tags.

Comment: Yes, after reading up a bit, I decided against using it in a table, and relegating it to a query instead. However, I'm still at a loss on how to use `DCount()` to do it, as in what the expression variables should be. Every time I run my query, it prompts me to enter a value for my table that comprises of the info on the subdatasheets.

Comment: I added an example of the DCount function.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for days. Thank you so much. It worked beautifully. Initially I was getting a syntax error so I enclosed the `ForeignKeyColumnInDetailTable` in square brackets and it worked perfectly!

Comment: If you dont mind explaining, what are all the extra quotes and the `&` signs for around `[KeyColumnControlNameOnMasterForm]`

Comment: The "D" functions -- DCount, DSum, DLookup -- take string parameters to identify, generally, the table column involved, the table, and a where condition. You could use a string variable for any one of these and it might be clearer to construct the where condition involved as a string and then pass the string in the function.

The ampersand is the string concatenation character in VBA.

The quotes are needed to identify a string within the string. What you're really passing to the function looks like this:

ForeignColumnInDetailTable = 'ControlName'

Comment: Actually since Access 2010 you *can* have a automatically updating calculated column. But It can't reference another table,

Comment: @Minty True, but none of the functions available for use in a calculated column can aggregate data across rows either. The calculated column value is limited to referencing and operating on values available on a single row of data.